# Adding spaces to keyword searches (Adobe)

Tags: javascript, adobe

I’m pretty new to coding and a coworker of mine and I are stuck. We’re building upon an existing script. How do we add spaces to a keyword search for a JavaScript extension in Adobe? We currently have one search function for all keywords, but would creating a search function for each keyword help?

Comment: would you mind sharing the code of the search function as well as what doesn't work in the modifications you attempted to achieve your goal?

Comment: Sorry for my delay in responding! Here is what we have been given:

function refSearch()
{
search.matchCase=false;
search.wordMatching="MatchingAnyWord";
search.bookmarks=false;
search.query("keyword keyword keyword....)
}

We have about 30 keywords, most are single word and are coming up no problem, are highlighting separately no problem, it's just a few keywords that are actually multi-word phrases that we need to add but don't know how. we tried underscores, quotations around spaces, nothing has worked so far. Would splitting each keyword in a new search.query help?

Thank you!